# Creating two distinct columns using WHERE clause from the same main table

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to pull two columns (B and C) from the same column (A) from Table_2. These two columns (script below) are implemented into a larger query. When I run the query with only one of the columns, for instance only B, then the query runs well and in just a few seconds. However, when I run both B and C within the query at the same time, the query just keeps running and does not end. I have tried giving the two columns different aliases to see if that would solve the problem, but I have not been able to figure out why the query does not run with both B and C present. The two columns are almost the same apart from the WHERE clause.

I only have one join in the script for both B and C columns similar to: FROM Table_1 T1, Table_2 T2 WHERE T2.ENT_REF = T1.ENT_REF (+)

Any ideas?

```
  ( SELECT  
      SUM(T2.A) as prem
      FROM Table_2 T2 
      WHERE T2.ENT_REF = T1.ENT_REF
      AND UPPER(T2.PER) = 'HURR' 
      AND UPPER(T2.ENT_TYPE) = 'POL'
      AND T2.Cov NOT IN ('OUTPROP','COV')
  ) B,


    (SELECT  
      SUM(T2.A) as prem
      FROM Table_2 T2 
      WHERE T2.ENT_REFE = T1.ENT_REF 
      AND UPPER(T2.PER) IN ('I', 'II', 'II') 
      AND UPPER(T2.ENT_TYPE) = 'POL'
      AND T2.Cov NOT IN ('OUTPROP','COV')
  ) C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the dummy table in PL/SQL. (From dual)

You also need to join the table (table_1).

Please make sure that every single query can return your expected value.

In your original queries, you put 'T2.ENT_REF = T1.ENT_REF' but you did not add the table_1. This will cause the syntax error.

Please try this:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT  
      SUM(T2.A) as prem
      FROM Table_2 T2, Table_2 T1
      WHERE T2.ENT_REF = T1.ENT_REF
      AND UPPER(T2.PER) = 'HURR' 
      AND UPPER(T2.ENT_TYPE) = 'POL'
      AND T2.Cov NOT IN ('OUTPROP','COV')
  ) as B,
  (SELECT  
      SUM(T2.A) as prem
      FROM Table_2 T2, Table_2 T1
      WHERE T2.ENT_REFE = T1.ENT_REF 
      AND UPPER(T2.PER) IN ('I', 'II', 'II') 
      AND UPPER(T2.ENT_TYPE) = 'POL'
      AND T2.Cov NOT IN ('OUTPROP','COV')
  ) as C
FROM DUAL
```

Update:

You can use [concat]

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
  (SELECT  
      SUM(T2.A) as prem
      FROM Table_2 T2, Table_2 T1
      WHERE T2.ENT_REF = T1.ENT_REF
      AND UPPER(T2.PER) = 'HURR' 
      AND UPPER(T2.ENT_TYPE) = 'POL'
      AND T2.Cov NOT IN ('OUTPROP','COV')
  ) ,
  (SELECT  
      SUM(T2.A) as prem
      FROM Table_2 T2, Table_2 T1
      WHERE T2.ENT_REFE = T1.ENT_REF 
      AND UPPER(T2.PER) IN ('I', 'II', 'II') 
      AND UPPER(T2.ENT_TYPE) = 'POL'
      AND T2.Cov NOT IN ('OUTPROP','COV')
  ) 
) AS BandC
FROM DUAL
```

Update 2:

```
SELECT
(
  (SELECT  
      SUM(T2.A) as prem
      FROM Table_2 T2, Table_2 T1
      WHERE T2.ENT_REF = T1.ENT_REF
      AND UPPER(T2.PER) = 'HURR' 
      AND UPPER(T2.ENT_TYPE) = 'POL'
      AND T2.Cov NOT IN ('OUTPROP','COV')
  ) +
  (SELECT  
      SUM(T2.A) as prem
      FROM Table_2 T2, Table_2 T1
      WHERE T2.ENT_REFE = T1.ENT_REF 
      AND UPPER(T2.PER) IN ('I', 'II', 'II') 
      AND UPPER(T2.ENT_TYPE) = 'POL'
      AND T2.Cov NOT IN ('OUTPROP','COV')
  ) 
) AS BandC
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped with my query running. On a side note, do you by any chance know how I can add columns B and C together? Before asking a separate question, thought I might try here first. So far I have tried a combination of something similar to: B.prem + C.prem but get an invalid C.prem identifier error.

Comment: Hi Gen, thanks so much for the above update. The concat worked in adding both values together side by side. It's a function I haven't tried yet and which will be useful in the next report I am writing which requires it, thus you have saved me some time in trying to figure that one out :) For this report however, I should have used the word SUM instead of add. I would like to SUM the values of B and C together.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help! That did it.